Is it possible to have more than one ASP.NET website in the same solution?
I bought hosting from a hosting company and I learned that I can only run one ASP.NET project on my hosting. Can I create multiple ASP.NET applications within one ASP.NET project?
So what I mean is this:
www.example.com/app1
www.example.com/app2

How do I do something like that?

A Solution is not a Project. An ASP.NET Web Application Project represents a single deployable web-application. A web-server (IIS) can be configured to serve multiple applications in the same Website (using different root paths, e.g. mywebsite.com/app1 and mywebsite.com/app2), but that requires special configuration ("IIS Application Scopes") and most web-application projects today do not support that scenario as they assume they live in the root of website. If you have control over all paths in your project(s) then yes, you can do this.

Based on your description, In your Visual Studio solution, create separate ASP.NET Core projects for each of your applications (e.g., app1, app2).
After that within your program.cs file you can use the Map method to route requests to different parts of your application based on the URL.

A solution can have multiple web apps. If you use the .NET Aspire tools, you'll create a solution with 3 web apps: 1 Web API, 1 Front end and 1 dashboard, each listening on different ports and/or virtual directories.

You can have many ASP.NET web projects in one solution but can host only one web project at a time as it seems in your hosting plan.
However, you can manage by creating multiple Areas/Controllers to separate logic in one web application with separate DLL projects for each app.
www.example.com/app1 - create Controller app1
www.example.com/app2 - create Controller app2

Yes, In a Visual studio solution you can add multiple projects . But best practice is to have seperate solution unless these are related .
Most common scenario is Adding a Web service/ Web Api and its UI web application together .
To create multiple projects ,

Open your first project in visual studio .
Right Click on solution icon , then click Add > New project as you wish( MVC, Api etc )
Once coding is completed for second project, you may choose required project as startup app to run locally .

You can even set multiple projects as startup application in Visual studio. Refer MS documentation for more info MS Link
